# vb.net code to make a image transparent

Tags: vb.net, image-processing, transparency

I wish to make a bitmap image (.bmp) transparent using VB.NET code. Kindly help me.

Answer (score 1):

I found the key was using the `imageAttributes` class.  Basically set the color key to the color you are using to represent the transparent area, and use one of the `drawImage` calls that accepts an `imageAttribute` parameter...

```
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging

' and in a sub somewhere:

Private mImageAttributes As New ImageAttributes
mImageAttributes.SetColorKey(Color.FromArgb(0, 220, 20, 255), 
Color.FromArgb(0, 220, 20, 255))

Dim imageRectangle As New Rectangle(pX, pY, pBitmap.Width, pBitmap.Height)
e.Graphics.DrawImage(pBitmap, imageRectangle, 0, 0, pBitmap.Width, pBitmap.Height,
GraphicsUnit.Pixel, mImageAttributes)
```

Answer (score 1):

VS 2012

Dim watermark_bm2 As Bitmap = 'someimage(from file or global resource)

watermark_bm2.MakeTransparent()

Answer (score 0):

This msdn article gives full details on [how to do this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172507.aspx)

Here is [another article, but code sample is in c#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/DrawTransparentImageUsingAB10102005010514AM/DrawTransparentImageUsingAB.aspx)