# Resizing image or crop images into specific shapes in vb

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to do a code for my application that will **crop a selected images into oval shape**.

I tried to search for a reference on the internet there is only example on how to resize it.
But is it possible to crop it into shapes?

Answer (score 0):

Images in .Net are always rectangular, there is no way to have an oval image or any other shape. What you *can* do is cut it down to its smallest possible rectangular form and make anything that would be outside of the shape [transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724292/vb-net-code-to-make-a-image-transparent).

As for using this now shaped-looking-Image, .Net seems to have a [problem using transparent images on Windows Forms](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/transparent_controls_net.aspx).